# What is the difference between a second order high pass filter and a low pass filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

What is the difference between a second order high pass filter and a low pass filter, apart from the location of the capacitors and resistors?

Comment: Hmm, one passes high frequencies and the other passes low frequencies?

Comment: The main difference is the passband. In a low pass filter, frequencies below Fc pass with less attenuation, and frequencies above Fc pass with more attenuation. But in a high pass filter it is the opposite: frequencies below Fc pass with more attenuation and frequencies above Fc pass with less attenuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts:

The *order* of a filter.

*High pass* versus *low pass*.

You seem to be really asking about high pass versus low pass.

These mean exactly what the name suggests.  A *high pass* filter passes high frequencies, and by implication, attenuates low frequencies.  A *low pass* filter does the reverse.

A simple single-pole RC filter can be idealized as having a flat (0 dB) response in the passband, then falling off 10 dB/decade from the rolloff point in the stop band.  In reality, the attenuation as a function of frequency is a smooth curve that approximates the two lines described above as asymptotes.  The attenuation is a factor of 2 (-6 dB gain) at the rolloff frequency.